# Function Netbeans Include Path

Tags: php, ide, netbeans

Did anybody know what is the function of include path in NetBeans?

I using netbeans 9.6.1

when we make new project there is will be two parent directory:
1. Source Files
2. Include Path

I didn't have idea what is include path,
can someone give explanation about this?

Comment: Didn't you tell the wrong NetBeans version? It's 2014 already and it stills in version 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the folders that will be scanned for code completion and hints. You can add folders by right clicking on project in project navigator, selecting `Properties` and going to `PHP Include Path` section

See here for in-depth tutorials on using NB for PHP development

http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html

Comment: Then it's means NetBeans will not read my commenting if i only put the class commenting in source folder?

Comment: It will, since the source folder is in include path anyway. It's more hassle in my opinion though.